# TheDoor Release Button on our Panasonic microwave oven Model NN-H275

Tags: kitchens

The door release button popped out on our microwave, can it be reinstalled?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info (e.g. can you post a picture of the problem?). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: does it make any difference what answer you get? ... it seems to me that if you have to ask, then you do not have the skill to do the repair ... take it to a repair shop